# post_import_function in App Engine bulkuploader yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bulkloader

I am trying to use post_import_function while uploading data using bulkloader.yaml. As per this link, [Using post_import_function in App Engine bulkuploader yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054701/using-post-import-function-in-app-engine-bulkuploader-yaml) , I am using type google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity for entity operations. As in the link, this is a subclass of 'dict'. However I am not sure how do I apply methods to this entity.

My code looks like (I am using Geomodel):

```
   def post_import_restaurants(input_dict, instance, bulkload_state_copy):

        lat = instance['lat']
        lng = instance['lng']
        latlng = "%s,%s" % (lat,lng)
        instance['location'] = db.GeoPt(latlng)
        instance.update_location()
        return instance
```

`instance.update_location()`, is where I am having issues. And I am not sure how to write this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add methods to an `Entity`. Just inline the code, or write it as a separate function that you pass the entity to.